# What is a correct way to prove the next propositional logic statement using Curry–Howard correspondence?

Tags: logic, type-theory

I am studying Curry–Howard correspondence.

Given propositional logic statement: `(¬p -> q) -> ((¬p -> ¬q) -> p)`.

I need to define a type (as proposition) and a function (as a proof) in OCaml.

I came up with the next code and stuck:

```
type empty = | ;; 
let ex58: (('p->empty) -> 'q) -> (('p->empty) -> ('q->empty)) -> 'p = fun f g -> g(f)
```

Error:

```
This expression has type ('p -> empty) -> 'q but an expression was expected of type 'p -> empty.
```

Comment: The given proposition is not intuitionistically valid, so a proof would have to involve something such as the `call-with-current-continuation` operation whose type corresponds to Peirce's law.

Comment: @DanielSchepler You are right. The proof involves: Double negation elimination of `p`. I did not know it before posting the question.
What does it mean “The given proposition is not intuitionistically valid” and how to show it? Did you try to prove it and found that a proof would have to involve:  Double negation elimination or Law of the excluded middle,…

Comment: Intuitionistic logic is a logic where principles such as excluded middle or double negation elimination are rejected.  It is especially relevant in study of the Curry-Howard correspondence, as the fragment of propositional logic where the proofs can be written as programs without using some sort of "execution rewinding" operation such as `call-with-current-continuation`.  (Or if you're using dependent types on the program side, then substitute "first-order logic" in place of "propositional logic" in the previous sentence.)

Comment: As for why the given proposition is not a theorem of intuitionistic logic: for example, in the special case where $q = \top$, then $\lnot p \rightarrow q$ is always true, and $\lnot p \rightarrow \lnot q$ is equivalent to $\lnot \lnot p$; so overall, that special case would imply the double negation elimination $\lnot \lnot p \rightarrow p$.  And double negation elimination is well-known not to be valid in intuitionistic logic.

Comment: So you did a basic analysis of the proposition and saw that it is not valid in intuitionistic logic. In general, is there some procedure to make sure there exists or not exists proof in intuitionistic logic? Given a type there is no function that implements it (without call-with-current-continuation).

Comment: I spent an hour trying to implement a function but it took only 15 min to prove it in classical logic and observe that we need Double negation elimination.

Comment: For propositional logic, there are complete proof search procedures which can tell you whether or not a given proposition is an intuitionistic tautology or not.  For first-order logic, it's more complex (just as it's a more complex question in classical logic) - but some tools that allow showing a proposition is not a theorem in intuitionistic logic include Kripke frames, Heyting algebra valued models, and sheaf models (topos theory).  (And these tools can also be useful for giving succinct proofs in the propositional logic case.)